# AdventureWorks entity not saving changes in the Database

Tags: c#, adventureworks

I want to insert an User in my Database, but the user is never stored in the Database.

When I'm on my breakpoint, I evaluate "db.tabUsers.Count()" and I can see that my tabUser contains the User that I'm creating. But when I go to my Table tabUser, no data was introduced.

My code :

```
 public void insertUser(string username ,string pwd)
        {
            var db = new AdventureWorksEntities();
            int IDForNewUser = db.tabUser.Max(u => u.intUserID);
            IDForNewUser++;

            var user = new User()
            {
               intID = IDForNewUser,
                strUsername = username,
                strPassword = pwd
            };

            tabUser userTable = new tabUser();
            userTable.intUserID = IDForNewUser;
            userTable.strUsername = username;
            userTable.strPassword = pwd;
            db.tabUser.Add(userTable);
            db.SaveChanges();
       } //BREAKPOINT IS HERE -- Evalutating db.TabUser.Count() and it is equal to 1
```

Comment: Could be many reasons not saving into database.

Debug and check the connection string property in DB context.

Run Sql profiler and see what's SQl it's generating.

Comment: I think it is not related but just out of curiosity, why do you create this user object? Another thing, are you sure the intUserID is not an identity column?

Comment: Could it be that you don't have auto-commit enabled?